# Why is the sizeof for a packed object lower than anticipated?

Tags: c++, sizeof, memory-alignment, pragma, memory-layout

I have the following code:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)

class C {
    public:
        char a;
        char b;
        short c;
        char d;
};
C e;
```

I don't understand why `sizeof(e)` is 6. 
I would thought that the `sizeof(e)` will be 8 => 1(a) + 1(b) + 2(c) + 1(d)  + 3 (for alignment)

Comment: yes. short is 2 bytes. char is 1 byte. if sizeof(e) equal the sum of its parts it should be 5. (because the alignment it is not..)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, with pragma pack, you can only decrease alignment, not increase. So this class behaves as if you didn't specify pragma pack at all (use alignas to increase alignment)

Comment: Ok. but still, why the padding is to number divide by 2 and not power of 2?  and also in this code i would expect sizeof will be 10, but its 12:   
     class  C {
 public:
  char a;
  char b;
  int c;
  short d;
};

Comment: Why would sizeof need to be a power of 2? Here, short has the largest alignment (2), so `C` size rounded up to be a multiple of 2.

Comment: your example contains `int`, which has alignment of 4, so its sizeof should be rounded up to a multiple of 4: 1 (char a) + 1 (char b) + 2 (padding) + 4 (int c) + 2 (short d) = 10, rounded up: 12.

Comment: so the rounding is according to biggest data type?

Comment: According to the largest alignment requirement (which is usually the biggest datatype, yes). Think about it: if it didn't do this, then putting `C` into an array, the second element would have bad alignment.

Comment: got it!  great! thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packing directive sets an upper bound for the alignment, not a minimum. The alignment requirement of `C` is only 2, so lowering the upper bound of alignment to 4 has no effect on it.

If you intend to increase the alignment, you can use `alignas` instead (which happens to be a standard feature, unlike packing).

> but still, why the padding is to number divide by 2 and not power of 2?

Because the size of an object only needs to be a multiple of the alignment of that object. It is that alignment which must be a power of 2.